# What is the minimum number of students without a triple friendship relationship?

Tags: graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

Any two pupils in the school are either friends or not, the friendship is mutual. For each integer 1 ≤ L ≤ 111 there is a school pupil having exactly L friends in the school.

Given that there is no triple of school pupils such that any two of them are friends, find the minimal possible number of pupils in this school.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: My answer would be 221 represented by a bipartite graph with 110 nodes left and 111 nodes right. From the pupil left we draw 111 edges to right, from right we draw 109 left (as 1 was already drawn), etc. Fewer pupils is impossible as this would always result in a non-triangle-free graph after the 111 and 110 constraints.

Comment: @jorisperrenet could you explain why you have the smallest side containing 110 nodes? I computed 56 and 111 for the two sides; but I may be wrong

Comment: @Qise, I think you may be right, starting from top to bottom with vertices on the left draw $111,110,\dots,57$ edges to the uppermost right vertices. The degrees of the right vertices become (from bottom to top) $1,2,3,\dots,54,55,$$55,\dots,55$. Draw one final edge from the bottom pupil on the left to the top pupil on the right to get the desired graph with vertices representing pupils and edges representing friendships.

Comment: hello friends, I asked the person who posted the question, unfortunately the answer was not 221.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is $ 111 + (111+1)/2 = 167 $. There are two parts in the answer, firstly we must show that we can achieve our goal with 167 people. Secondly we need to show that we cannot do it with less. For the second, assume that we have a graph with the desired properties and we begin drawing it by first drawing one of the people with 111 friends, then one with 110 (if not already there) and so on. We start with 112 people where the first is a friend of all the others and there is no friendship between the others. You have a person with 111 friends and (a lot of) people with one friend. At the second step you must add at least one person and all his friendships. Other than the the persons with 111 and 110 friends, everybody else on the graph has at most two friends. With this reasoning we see that until $111+1/2$ we are forced to add an extra person to our graph. This shows that we cannot have a graph with less than $ 111 + (111+1)/2 = 167 $ people.
As for he first part it is explained in the comments.

Comment: thanks, the first thing that came to our mind was to connect 109 friends to one of the 111 people who have 111 friends. This solution was increasing the number of students. The method you mentioned is optimum.